# How many different options do you have for selecting 8 of these balls?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

You have 6 red balls, 3 of which are identical & the other 3 are distinct & different from the previous 3, 4 distinct orange balls, 6 identical purple balls. You want to select 8 balls. How many different options do you have?

I tried using the combinations formula (i.e. 16!/8!(8!)) but I know this is wrong because of the identical balls, which would reduce the total number of options. I can't find any worked textbook examples accounting for identical objects in combinations. I'm guessing there will be a subtraction involved.

Comment: Have you made any progress on this problem? What has been your attempt so far?

Comment: @CraveableBanana I tried using the combinations formula (i.e. 16!/8!(8!)) but I know this is wrong because of the identical balls, which would reduce the total number of options. I can't find any worked textbook examples accounting for identical objects in combinations. I'm guessing there will be a subtraction involved.

Comment: In future, please include your attempt in the question rather than the comments, where they might be missed.

Answer (score 1):

You are right that we have to consider the identical balls. There are $3$ identical red balls and $6$ identical purple balls which really confuse the problem. Besides these $9$ tricky balls, though, we can consider the other $16 - 9 = 7$ balls to be completely distinct, as even the distinct balls of the same color can be told apart.

One approach is to just sum over all the cases. This may not be the neat closed form you might expect, but it works. Let $r$ be the number of the identical red balls chosen, and $p$ be the number of identical purple balls chosen. Then the total number of options is
$$ \sum_{r = 0}^3 \sum_{p = 0}^{\min(6, 8 - r)} {7 \choose 8 - r - p}. $$
For any fixed $r$ and $p$, the problem reduces to choosing the remaining $8 - r - p$ from the $7$ distinct balls, hence the standard combinations formula. The $\min(6, 8 - r)$ is because we cannot exceed $8$ balls with the number of red and purple we choose.